# Customization to Contact record page

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

We like the layout of the Contact record page (split view).  How can I do these additional configuration on the Search Area:

- How can we reduce the width?
- How can we remove the status message?

If it is not possible to change these items, what are my options?

[image: Contact Record split view page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of a lightning page component is derived from its parent container (i.e. Lightning Page Template Component).

In order to change it, your can build a template yourself using Lightning Aura.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm)

[Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a component aware of its record context by giving it a property named `recordId` and decorated with `@api`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/use_record_context